# How to play animation of different GameObject in Unity?

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine

I have several gameObjects in my scene, let's say two: `Button` and `Controller(empty GameObject)`;
I keep all the code in the script attached to `Controller`, this script contains method `onButtonClick()` which should start the animation of Button.
Button already has Animator component with working animation(when it is ticked, animation starts automatically after starting the game).
How can I launch this animation from Controller on button click? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the reference of the GameObject in your script and via inspector assign it.

In your controller script:

```
public GameObject obj;
public Button myButton;


void Start(){
     myButton.onClick.AddListener(()=> {
     obj.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("myAnim");
});

}
```

Doing that you will be ok.

PS: Dont put all your code in a single script, I advise you to learn about  Single-responsibility Principle, this way you will keep your code simple and easy to fix in future bugs